# Why is RSelenium always giving an error when I want to define a Firefox profile

Tags: r, firefox, browser, rselenium

I am using RSelenium and want to set a Firefox profile. So I tried to reproduce the example of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759438/rselenium-popup?rq=1). However, no matter what I change I always get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

I already read in the RSelenium manual that for windows systems RTools should be installed when one wants to make a Firefox profile. I did but nothing changed.

The error is the following:

```
Error in file(tmpfile, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command '"zip" -r9Xjq "C:\Users\mariu\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQfl3bl\file15c41fc2411d.zip" "C:\Users\mariu\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQfl3bl/firefoxprofile/prefs.js" ' had status 127 
2: In file(tmpfile, "rb") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\mariu\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQfl3bl\file15c41fc2411d.zip': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that Rselenium cannot create a zip file of your Firefox Profile (error status 127), therefore cannot read it in the next command line.

I resolved following this answer:
[Create zip file: error running command " " had status 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127) .

Do as the link says , shut down R, restart your pc and it should work.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, for some reasons, it is not enough to add *Rtools* file location to *Environmental Variables* as was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129681/create-zip-file-error-running-command-had-status-127). To solve the problem you need to add path within R using folowing code:

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
```

Then PC needs to be reseted. After that you can check whether path was setted correctly.

```
Sys.which("make")
## "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe
```

If output of `sys.which` is `""` then something went wrong. By the way the entire procedure has been described here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.